# how this equation is obtained for calculating input capacitor of a fly back presented in UC3842 datasheet?

Tags: capacitor, switch-mode-power-supply, rectifier, flyback, input

i know that it refers to stored energy formula for a capacitor according to voltage variations. but i dont have any idea about the specified part. where did this part come from?
https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/uc3842 page 23

[image]
[image]

Comment: A definition of Vbulk ought to be provided.

Comment: i dont think so. Vbulk_min is pre-considered as 75volts (where as the min Vrms is 85 and it is also a question that why 75)

Comment: But, what is Vbulk on the circuit? Where is the circuit that this formula applies to? Is Vbulk the Cin capacitor voltage?

Comment: the link of uc3842 datasheet and corresponding page is mentioned in question whcih contains the topology and circuit. yes, Vbulk is the output dc voltage of rectifier.

Comment: \$\arcsin(v_{bulk}/v_{in, peak})\$ would give the phase angle over which the input is below the vbulk. Division by \$\pi\$ probably converts it to fraction of input AC time period. Don't know why it is added to 1/4 and multiplied to the P_in.

Comment: I’ve just attached a new file explaining the existence of P_in in above-mentioned formula. Can you have a conclusion??